# Why the promise works in the same time?

Tags: javascript

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1)
    resolve()
  }, 200)
  
}).then(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(2)
    resolve()
  }, 0)
  
}))
```

Why this output is 2  1,not 1 2?
The promise should do things in order?Why it happens

Comment: They may *start* in order, but you used a timeout, so...

Comment: Because use different timeout times. Try to set *both* to 0 (or 200 or whatever).

Comment: It's not the timeouts, it's that the OP creates the second promise immediately and passes the promise to then, instead of passing a function that creates the second promise and thereby deferring its creation.

Comment: `then()` expects a callback function

Answer (score 3):

`then`'s first parameter is a callback function. Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then.

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(1)
        resolve()
    }, 200)
}).then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(2);
         resolve();
    }, 0)});
});
```

Comment: You should return the second promise from the callback, otherwise any further chaining won't work as expected either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Thanks :)